# Computations for Quantum Vacuum Fluctuations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, cosmology

For quite some time the notion of *quantum vacuum fluctuations* is bothering me.

**What exactly is the theoretical origin of this notion?** This notion has become quite common in physics and is used to predict quite sophisticated effects. For example the Hawking radiation, where a particle pair pops into existence from the vacuum at the horizon of a black hole and one falls into the black hole and the partner escapes. So far I've failed to find a computation for this process of particle creation and annihilation in the vacuum from nothing.

In many books these notions are motivated somewhat vague using the Heisenberg time uncertainty relation

$$  \Delta t  \Delta E > h $$

For a short time interval $\Delta t$ the conservation of energy can be violated by $\Delta E$ and therefore we can have a particle pair with energy $\Delta E$ pop into existence from nothing, as long as they vanish after $\Delta t$. This is quite a nice idea, but their is no "time operator" in quantum mechanics and therefore the interpretation of the equation $\Delta t  \Delta E > h $ isn't as straight-forward as $\Delta p  \Delta x > h $ etc. It is possible to find arguments that point into the direction energy violation for a short period of time, but I never found them fully satisfactory when it comes to particle creation and annihilation from nothing.

I think the appropriate framework for this kind of thing should be Quantum Field Theory, because particle creation and annihilation is what QFT is all about.

**What process or computation is the theoretical basis for Vacuum Fluctuations?** Maybe the disconnected Feynman graphs that accompany regular Feynman graphs? Nevertheless, these do not happen in a vacuum but only as attachment to regular processes.  Are there computations of the form

$$ <0| \mathrm{ \ Vacuum \  Fluctuations \ } |0> $$

that lead to predictions or statements about *vacuum fluctuations*?

**Any idea or reference would be awesome!**

Comment: I would recommend reading up on either the Casimir effect, where vacuum fluctuations can be experimentally measured, or the Schwinger effect, where an external electric field can rip the virtual pairs into existence. BTW, in terms of Feynman diagrams the virtual pairs are represented by loops.

Comment: _What process is the theoretical basis for Vacuum Fluctuations?_  My understanding is that we can only measure frequency to a certain degree of accuracy, This implies that we can measure time only to a certain degree of precision also.  So that always leaves us, using the uncertainty principle quoted in your post, with some uncertainity regarding the amount of energy associated with the fluctation. To my knowledge, the Uncertainty Principle is simply a law of nature, similiar to the speed of light value being ~300 000 km/s. It's a given, with no proven theoretical basis as of today.

Comment: @irishphysics Correct, and the underlying principle is that the universe appears to be built on (matter) waves. Hence it is the Fourier transform that mediates between observables, both in the proper Heisenberg uncertainty relations _and_ in the improper one between time and energy (which is angular frequency times $hbar$).

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168398/50583) because both really ask *"What is a quantum fluctuation?"*. I recommend reading in particular Leandro M.'s answer here. tl;dr: The notion of quantum fluctuation is ill-defined, and you should be quite wary as soon as someone says "uncertainty principle", arguments involving it are often handwavy and not at all rigorous. See also [What is a vacuum fluctuation in laymen's terms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16851/50583).

Comment: Also, the time-energy uncertainty principle is tricky because it is *not* the same as the other uncertainty relations, see [what is $\Delta t$ in the uncertainty principle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583)? What comes to light in all of this: It is probably best to simply *not* talk of "quantum fluctuations", since the term is either vaguely defined or trivial.

Comment: I might write an answer later, but for now I just want to point out that if you look up pedagogical treatments of "virtual particles" you will probably find information relevant to this question. What you're calling "vacuum fluctuations" and what people call "virtual particles" are very closely related concepts.

Comment: @DanielSank. If you do write an answer could you please include a reference to the words _somewhat vague_ in the OP. I had thought that the uncertainty principle was not at all vague, but acuriousmind's comments mean that I am now not at all certain that the uncertainty principle is as straightforward as I originally thought, if you get my drift. What's incorrect or trivial in calling them quantum fluctuations? I can ask this as a separate question if required. Thank you

Comment: @ACuriousMind Uhm really? My question is about vacuum fluctuations and not quantum flucutations per se. The story I describe in the OP is told in many standard books and lectures: Because of Quantum Mechanics we have particles pop into existence in the vacuum. (This is different from the virtual particles that accompany standard processes in QFT). My question is specifically about the theoretical framework that is used to describe such processes. There must exist sth to justify this, because otherwise ideas like the Hawking radiation or the Unruh effect wouldn't be taken so seriously...?!

Comment: @ACuriousMind and regarding the uncertainty principle... that's exactly what I wrote in my question

Comment: Virtual particles don't *exist*, Unruh and Hawking don't need them. They're internal lines in Feynman diagrams, and don't exist in non-perturbative or non-diagrammatic approaches to QFT. Have a look at the [vacuum fluctuation portion of Neumaier's FAQ](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/physfaq/topics/vacfluc) - a "vacuum fluctuation" is just a fancy and unnecessary name for a non-zero expectation value that looks like a variance, and for some reason people like to call that "fluctuation". Again, I recommend [Leandro M.'s answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168435/50583) on fluctuations.