# Quantum fluctuations in early universe

Tags: cosmology

Why do quantum fluctuations of fields arise at high energies and temperatures?

What is the mathematical formulation of these quantum fluctuations?

Why are the sizes of these quantum fluctuations approximately the Planck size?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "quantum fluctuation" here?

Comment: That exactly is my question. People throw around this phrase all the time.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168398/50583 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16851/50583 for some related discussion of this confusing and rather difficult to nail down phrase.