# Empty Space type of energy

Tags: spacetime, vacuum

What is empty space?

What kinds of energy are in empty space?

What is the process by which the raw energy of space condenses to form matter?

Answer (score 1):

3 different questions but let's give it a try, since they are related.

1. Empty space, or really empty spacetime is space, or spacetime with no matter or radiation particles, and in general relativity (GR) that means a stress energy tensor of zero in that region of spacetime. Still, it may have some vacuum fluctuations, see answer to 2.
2. Quantum theory tells us that the value of different quantum fields, even if zero on the average and in their ground states, will have fluctuations. Those fluctuations have fluctuations as do most quantum entities, they come and go, and last a small period of time, with the time durations roughly given by the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle (HUP) that relates the energy and time variances. It is believed that somehow (but this is not fully figured out, still a mystery) those quantum fields, there even in vacuum, are somehow responsible for the Dark Energy that is the cosmological constant that has a very small but cosmologically relevant energy contribution to the universe.

   We do not know how the numbers are what they are, but that [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) contributes about 70% of the universe's energy, yet we still don't know exactly how.
3. No, the vacuum energy of space or spacetime does not condense to form matter or other forms of energy. It seems to be staying constant during the universe's evolution. So what forms matter: it is believed to have come with the universe, except in a different form. A few instants (see the reference below for when) after the Big Bang, a quantum field which is called the Inflaton field started decaying down to its ground state and releasing all the energy it had stored up into a large amount of different particles and radiation, from which eventually came the elementary particles like electrons, gluons, quarks and other things, that formed the matter and energy we see today.

   [Inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) was invented years back to explain some other issues in cosmology (mostly why the universe is so homogeneous and isotropic) and is based on some Inflaton field which has still not been nailed down. It is accepted as part of modern cosmology, but with some trepidation and purist observationalists will say we can model the universe from then on. But theoretically and some observations point to something like inflation.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to desktop Wikipedia pages rather than [mobile Wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Enable_mobile_version), e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)

Comment: I've been doing a lot of this on my iPad, the mobile comes up automatically. How do I get the desktop version?

Comment: At the bottom of the mobile page click on 'Desktop'.

Comment: Alternatively, delete the `m.` in the link manually.

Comment: On the content of the post itself, I agree with most things except for the perpetuation of "vacuum fluctuations" being "virtual" and "related to the HUP". For the proper interpretation of the time-energy uncertainty principle, see [this question and its answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583). What do you mean by a "fluctuation" here, and why is it "virtual"? (Cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16851/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168398/50583 for other discussions of this term)

Comment: @Qmechanic and ACuriousMind. Thanks, will plan to do. ACuriousMind, I agree the fluctuations are not virtual, and that is due to normal fluctuations of the field in QFT. I'll fix the wording. The HUP just says roughly how long the energy fluctuations last, and I'll read if your reference invalidates that or it's just words

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Yes, saw your reference, the HUP is right but of course not the source. Still, a bit of wordsmanship.

Comment: @CuriousMind, let me know if you think the words or concepts, as modified, are not good.